# pullback of a 1-form computation

Tags: differential-geometry

I am learning how to compute a pullback of a 1-form. My reference does not provide many examples, and those few there are utterly trivial that reduce to 0... I am wondering how one might compute something like:
\begin{equation}
\phi^*(x^2dy + y^2dx),
\end{equation}
where $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$, $t\mapsto (t,t^2)$.

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange. Please, show your efforts about the subject and we will can help you more.

Comment: I assume $x$ and $y$ are the standard coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^2$? Sanity check: can you pull back 0-forms? What is $\phi^*(y)$? $\phi^*(x^2)$? You should probably name the stanard coordinate on $\mathbb{R}$ too. (and give it a name that isn't $x$ or $y$. Don't give it the name $t$ either if you want to use $t$ as a dummy variable)

Comment: They only had an example where the coefficient of $dy$ reduces to 0 because $t\mapsto (2t,0)$. I have no idea in general cases, hence the reason I am asking for a worked-out example, so that I may do other problems...

Comment: Hurkyl: The example they had is as follows (right to the notation): $\phi:t\mapsto (t,0)$, and compute $\phi^*(xdy+ydx)$. They did it: $t(d0)+0(dt) = 0$.

Comment: $\phi^*(y) = t^2$, and $\phi^*(x^2)=t^2$, I suppose.

Comment: If you're learning the basics of differential forms, you might find some of my [lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd) linked in my profile helpful. In particular, Day 27 of the second course is labeled "Pullback." But you'll find lots of examples as you proceed, along with proofs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pullbacks of forms work exactly like variable substitution.

For example, if we have standard variables $r, \theta$ on one copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $x,y$ on a second copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the transformation $\phi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 : (a,b) \mapsto (a \cos(b), a \sin(b))$ has pullback given by

- $\phi^*(x) = r \cos(\theta)$
- $\phi^*(y) = r \sin(\theta)$

and pullbacks commute with exterior derivatives: $\mathrm{d} \phi^*(s) = \phi^*(\mathrm{d} s)$. e.g.

$$ \phi^*(\mathrm{d}x) = \mathrm{d}(r \cos(\theta))$$

---

For a proof that this works, suppose you're given a differentiable map $\phi : M \to N$.

Consider the manifold $M \times N$, along with the pais $p : M  \times N \to M$ and $q : M \times N \to N$ defined by simply taking the first or second coordinate.

The point of doing this is to construct a space in which we can *simultaneously* work with both the coordinate functions of $M$ and the coordinate functions of $N$.

This manifold has a submanifold $S \subseteq M \times N$ consisting only of the points $(m, \phi(m))$; this is nothing more than the graph of the function $\phi$!

But the point is that $S$ is diffeomorphic to $M$ in the obvious way, so we can work with $S$ as if it were the same thing as $M$.

Going back to the example above, the point is that on the manifold $M$, we have the four scalar fields $x,y,r,\theta$. When restricted to the submanifold $S$, the relationship between them is literally just equations: $x = r \cos(\theta)$ and $y = r \sin(\theta)$.

Comment: Thanks! I get what you are saying in the first part though. My main concern is what to do with things like $d(r\cos\theta)$, or $d(t^2)$. Do I, as I did in ordinary calculus class, $dt^2=2t(dt)$?